# Mysql SUM with UNION ALL and JOIN

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 tables and I like to get sum of values and also to group by the result.

I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(tr_amount) as total, projects.pr_type
    from transactions 
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pr_name = transactions.tr_pr_name
    WHERE tr_amount < '0'
    GROUP BY projects.pr_type

UNION ALL 

SELECT SUM(tr_pr_price) as total, projects.pr_type
    from transactions 
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pr_name = transactions.tr_pr_name
    WHERE tr_type = '1' 
    GROUP BY projects.pr_type
```

and I get this answer:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| total | pr_type               |
+-------+-----------------------+
| -3720 | Christening           |
| -1640 | Wedding               |
|  -820 | Wedding - Christening |
| 10410 | Christening           |
|   350 | Photoshooting         |
|  6650 | Wedding               |
|  2500 | Wedding - Christening |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

The goal is to sum Christening with Christening etc, so the result will be :

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| total | pr_type               |
+-------+-----------------------+
|  6690 | Christening           |
|   350 | Photoshooting         |
|  5010 | Wedding               |
|  1680 | Wedding - Christening |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

I try this but give error:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM(
SELECT SUM(tr_amount) as total, projects.pr_type
    from transactions 
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pr_name = transactions.tr_pr_name
    WHERE tr_amount < '0'
    GROUP BY projects.pr_type

UNION ALL 

SELECT SUM(tr_pr_price) as total, projects.pr_type
    from transactions 
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pr_name = transactions.tr_pr_name
    WHERE tr_type = '1' 
    GROUP BY projects.pr_type) as test
    GROUP BY projects.pr_type
```

> Unknown column 'projects.pr_type' in 'group statement'

Comment: Can you create a superset between both accounting for all records and validate you get your intended results.  Then either create a CTE, temp table, or outer query and aggregate your results that way?

Answer (score 0):

5 min later , i decide to ask chatgpt, i was just curius!
And i get this answer

```sql
SELECT pr_type, SUM(total) as combined_total
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(tr_amount) as total, projects.pr_type
    FROM transactions
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pr_name = transactions.tr_pr_name
    WHERE tr_amount < '0'
    GROUP BY projects.pr_type

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(tr_pr_price) as total, projects.pr_type
    FROM transactions
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pr_name = transactions.tr_pr_name
    WHERE tr_type = '1'
    GROUP BY projects.pr_type
) AS subquery
GROUP BY pr_type;
```